How to achieve hierarchical tags in my bookmarks?
I am trying to browse my numerous bookmarks easily and quickly and to find every bookmark related to a sum of topics and matching a typology of content.
When it comes to organizing items for convenience, should it be files, bookmarks or any other kind of item, there seems to be only two ways to go:
folders
Example:

Media Tools

Image editors
Sound editors


Tech stuff

Computer stuff
Mobile stuff



The problem being that items can belong in several places (a mobile image editor app can go under Tools > Image editors or under Tech > Mobile)
tags
Media Tools Image editors Sound editors Tech stuff Computer stuff Mobile stuff
The problem being that this is not convenient to browse when you have a lot of tags, and that you don't see the hierarchy between for example Media Tools and Image editors.
However, I can think of a way to combine the best of the two worlds: hierarchical tags. It enables to navigate a tree in an intuitive way, however the tree levels are tags, so you can find what you're looking for displayed under several folders-tags. It also enables to conceptualize different kind of tags, like a very simple database model, e.g. for language, license, etc.
Example:

Media Tools

Image editors

[that mobile img editor app]


Sound editors


Tech stuff

Computer stuff
Mobile stuff

[that same mobile img editor app]





I have been looking for a very long time for a bookmarks manager that has this feature and I never found it. The result for "hierarchical tags" or "tag tree" doesn't provide any evidence that this feature exist anywhere in software. How is that possible? Am I missing a major drawback of that compromise? How would you achieve my goal instead?

Thanks, but this is not a software recommandation request...?!!

No, because, quoting, "The result for "hierarchical tags" or "tag tree" doesn't provide any evidence that this feature exist anywhere in software". I am actually asking, quoting again, "How is that possible? Am I missing a major drawback of that compromise? How would you achieve my goal instead?" I don't understand why this question has been closed. Maybe it's off-topic as too academic but this is not a software reco request although answers might include software for example purposes.

I see. Thanks for your input.

I reccomend that you post a software rec request as that is your best shot of solving this. Outside of that you would need to code sonething. PS: I also think it odd. With Google it's labels and more labels, then... folders!?
